# Debugging Twitter API's error code: 89

Tags: node.js, twitter, npm

When I run my app, I get this error message, and I'm not entirely sure why.

> [ { code: 89, message: 'Invalid or expired token.' } ]

It was working a little over a week ago, and I even generated tokens for a new application, and I'm still receiving the error.

I've tried looking into this, and I've tried everything from a new application, reinstalling node packages. I'm currently trying to use the twitter node package here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/twitter

According to documentation, my usage was right, and I can confirm the same code was working about a week ago.

```
var Twitter = require('twitter');
var auth = require('../config/twitter.js');

var client = new Twitter({
  consumer_key: auth['consumer_key'],
  consumer_secret: auth['consumer_secret'],
  access_token: auth['access_token'],
  access_token_secret: auth['access_token_secret']
});

client.get('statuses/user_timeline', {screen_name: 'lrroberts0122', count: 10}, function(error, tweets) {
  if(error) {
    console.log(error);
  } else {
    console.log(tweets);
  };
});
```

I can also confirm with absolute certainty that the keys are being pulled accurately from my config file.

I'm just trying to get the statuses of the user timeline - the last 'x' amount of tweets from a specified user. I wasn't using any kind of authentication or Oauth aside from my own for the API - so I'm not sure if I need to implement something now.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! =)

Thank you very much for your help!

As an added note, I did take a look at this SO question: [Twitter application oauth started returning error code 89 Invalid or expired token after 1 year working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27396976/twitter-application-oauth-started-returning-error-code-89-invalid-or-expired-tok)

But I'm not sure if it applies in what I'm trying to do.

This is a barebones node application, so there's really not much other than what I already have. Please let me know if there's any additional information you might need.

Comment: Generate new access token and try with that. ref: https://twittercommunity.com/t/solved-errors-message-invalid-or-expired-token-code-89/10797/11

Answer (score 0):

Generate new access token and try with that. ref: https://twittercommunity.com/t/solved-errors-message-invalid-or-expired-token-code-89/10797/11

Comment: I created a new one but I get the same error message